# Is it valid to omit the subject when starting the sentence with "his [subject] is"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have the following:

> Joe helps me with validating my ideas. His voice is a voice of reason I can count on.

I don't like the repetition of "voice", though. I think I can rewrite the second sentence this way:

> His is a voice of reason I can count on.

I feel like I've seen such a construct before and I think it's correct, but I'm not sure. Is it?

Comment: Yes, there's no problem whatever with it.

Comment: Great! Does this phrasing have any special grammatical term associated with it? How would you reason that this is grammatically correct? You can post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I suppose the 'grammatical term' you're asking about is _ellipsis_ —a form of omission of one or more words from a sentence/clause that are nevertheless understood in the context of the other elements of the sentence/clause. This one above is probably the simplest case of _ellipsis_.

Comment: "Ellipsis" isn't really a grammatical term. It just means "something's missing", with no indication of what it is (or was), why it's missing, or what rule it's following. Handwaving, not description. English has dozens of specific deletion rules; this would be the substitution of a possessive personal pronoun for the noun phrase it possesses, which is echoed later in the clause. Though it doesn't need to be -- _Yours is bigger than his_ is equally understandable, in context (or we can and often do dream up a context for it).

Comment: Is this not purely a style choice? Either way, I see no subject omitted.